How express our bullish views on the credit options market?
I am reading a handbook from Morgan Stanley about Credit Derivatives Insights. There is a part about the payoffs of a put option(payer option/ right to buy a protection) and a call option (receiver option/right to sell a protection).
So, they are inversed in comparaison of the payoffs in the stock options market. But after there is a part about the directionally bullish strategies and apparently one basical strategy is to buy  call (receiver/right to sell a protection) but I don't understand why. Because, in my opinion, if I buy a call with  a strike at 110bp, the spot is at 100bp if tomorrow the spot become 120bp, the intrinsic value of my call option (in credit market) is K-S = 100-120 = -20bp, so I'm OTM ! Can you explain me what is wrong with my explanation ? Thanks you

related https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/80423
